# How to create gate symbol in quantikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, quantikz

I want to define a gate in quantikz with my own shape. Let's say I want a triangular gate or $\odot$ (instead of the usual CNOT or the square with letter). How can this be achieved? I looked at the examples in the documentation but I did not find anything similar.

For example, imagine adding a gate that looks like an inverter:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide an example how you wish the shape to look like and how it would be used in the context of a `quantikz` diagram? This might make it easier to help you.

Comment: @JasperHabicht updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `quantikz` just uses regular shapes for the nodes, you can use those that are predefined in one of the `circuit.logic` libraries that come with Ti*k*Z (see chatper 49.3 "Logical Circuits" in the [Ti*k*Z/PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), page 618 ff).

As for the `\odot`-like shaped node, I guess you will have to define it from scratch. I am also unsure how to use it, since the dot makes it difficult to add text to the node ... Anyways, here is my suggestion:

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{quantikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US}

\tikzset{
    gateT/.style={
        draw,
        not gate US,
        inner sep=5pt
    },
    gateO/.style={
        draw,
        circle,
        minimum width=1.67em,
        inner sep=2pt,
        append after command={
            \pgfextra {
                \fill (\tikzlastnode) circle[radius=1pt];
            }
        }
    }
}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\gateT}{O{}{m}}{|[gateT,#1]| {#2} \qw}
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\gateO}{O{}{m}}{|[gateO,#1]| {#2} \qw}

\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
    \lstick{$A$} & 
    \gateT{H} & 
    \gate{H} & 
    \gateO{} & 
    \qw \rstick{$B$}
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that solves part of my issue. Would you be able to put some predefined latex symbol on the wire as well? Like an $\odot$?

Comment: @Mauricio Sorry, I don't know what this shape should look like. Like a circle with a dot in the middle?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Like the [alchemical sun glyph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suns_in_alchemy) or any other symbol in latex that could be shaped nicely on a wire.

Comment: @Mauricio I think this is a bit strange, since nodes normally allow to add some text, but if there is a dot inside the node, where should the text go? Anyways, see the edit to my answer.

Comment: This works good enough, thanks!